# Django Html get dictionary value from index

Tags: python, html, django

How can I get the value from my dictionary using the forloop counter? The current way that I'm doing it doesn't show anything.

**Extension.py**

```
@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

**Views.py**

```
{% for project in projectList %}
       <tr>
           <td><h5>{{ project.id }}</h5></td>
           <td><h5>${{ project.allBudgets|get_item:forloop.counter0 }}</h5></td>
       </tr> 
{% endfor %}
```

**All Budgets:**

```
{'2021/2022': Decimal('75'), '2022/2023': Decimal('50')}
```

Comment: what is the value of `project.allBudgets` ? can you log it here

Comment: Are you sure `project.allBudgets` is a dictionary and not a list?

Comment: @EneP Updated mate

Comment: With this `allBudgets` variable, `forloop.counter0` must be `'2021/2022'` or `'2022/2023'`. Try to show `{{ forloop.counter0 }}` only in the template.

Comment: That's because project.allBudgets is a dict with string keys. forloop.counter0 returns 0,1,2 etc.. Of cource nothing is showing. You need to pass the actual key not an index.

Comment: No, that's bad practice, since dictionaries don't guarantee order. Just use the keys.